# How to force numpy to accept objects as float?

Tags: python, numpy, object, floating-point

Right now numpy throws an error if I try to feed it objects when dtype = 'float'

However floats are also an object. How can I make numpy treat my object like a float?

Edit: I have an object that returns a float upon multiplication and addition. I want to treat it as a float as it becomes a float after a linear transformation.

So my object:

```
Class some_class()
    def __init__(self,a)
        self.a=a
    def __mul__(self.x):
        Return float(a*x)
    ...
   def __radd__(self,x):
        return float(a+x)
```

How do I get it to interrupt this as a float?

Edit 2: am I fundamentally misinterpreting dtype? My logic is that as it behaves like a float it should be treated as such. Is this just wrong?  I also ask this question because np.exp() and np.dot() don't seem to work for object types, even if they behave like that.

Edit3: thanks everyone for teaching me about dtypes and astype functions :)

Comment: `None` is an object, so is `[]` and `{'a':3}`.  None of those can be stored as a float.  Trying to do `float(None)` produces an error.

Comment: Can you write command, you use?

Comment: This is the classic squares and rectangles question. All floats are (interpretable as) objects, but not all objects are (interpretable as) floats.

Comment: Why do you even *have* `dtype=float` if you want to put things that aren't floats in your array?

Comment: Numpy arrays are homogeneous -- if you set dtype = 'float' that is the only type it will hold. Even you set the array to Python objects, it is homogenous collection of one object type -- Python object.

Comment: @user2357112 because the objects behave like floats. Maybe I'm fundamentally misinterpreting.

Comment: If the `dtype=object` the array's databuffer will contain pointers to objects else where in memory.  Or rather it will have bytes which will be interpreted as pointers.  It's not all that different from a list, which stores pointers.

Comment: @Perm.Questiin: NumPy dtypes are not based on what the contents behave like (and even if they were, your objects don't behave *enough* like floats). NumPy dtypes are extremely closely tied to the in-memory representation of a NumPy array. A `dtype=float` array holds a buffer of raw 8-byte floating-point numbers; it cannot accept other objects. Hell, it doesn't even hold float *objects* at all.

Comment: "My logic is that as it behaves like a float it should be treated as such. Is this just wrong?" - in the context of NumPy dtypes, that's just wrong.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you

Comment: With arrays of dtype object, it is hit-or-miss as to which math operations work.  Even when they do work, they are slower than with regular numeric arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to typecast your resultant numpy array to float values then use `astype($TYPE)`

```
>>> x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
>>> x
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])
>>>
>>> x.astype(float)
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])
```

Refer [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) link for more information.

Comment: Glad to help ;)